# Does Islam allow celebrating the attainment of puberty?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, modesty, ritual

I have observed a few cultures that throw a party, calling upon their relatives and close friends for lunch or dinner to acknowledge when their daughter has reached puberty.

While I have read that back in the day, this was signal to look for potential daughter in laws, given that nowadays most girls tend to marry only after college, are such displays and rituals still relevant?

Also are the girls not made uncomfortable knowing their body changes are being inexplicitly announced among their cousins?

If Islam allows this, why do we not have a similar ritual for the boys similar to the Jews?

Comment: Are you referring to a bar mitzvah?

Comment: Yes, more like Bnei mitzvah for both boys and girls.

Answer (score -1):

The celebration of maturity or obligation in Islam is permitted and good. This celebration is common among the Shiites. But , the motivation of this maturity celebration is different in Shiite.

It is considered to be a religious maturity. Because we have been rational and physical, we have reached the extent that God orders us, and we are glad to obey the desires and orders of God and be a good servant of ourselves. With the "puberty celebration", we are grateful blessings, and we remember this big day in which we have reached the age of religious puberty, as a day of Major and memorable memory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If possible, can you share a "Daleel" so that it will be easier for us to explain to others with proofs.